# Avoid NameError while defining a self using class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to create a python class which require another instance of the same class for some methods, but I get a NameError.

Here is a quick example :

```py
class test(object):
    def met(self,other:test):
        pass
```

when parsing this python raise a `NameError`, this error comes from the fact that for python the name `test` still doesn't exist while parsing his methods (or at least the methods header).

My question is : how to avoid this `NameError` while keeping the obligation for the type of `other` in the function header(ie not using an `isinstance` like function in the method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose forward references to types defined later in quotes, like this:

```py
class test(object):
    def met(self,other:'test'):
        pass
```

This is explained in [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)